# How to use wired and wireless interfaces simultaneously?

Tags: 12.04, networking, process, interface, sockets

When creating any socket, we don't provide a device name (like eth0, or wlan0). On my laptop, I have a wired interface (eth) and a wireless interface (wlan). I want to run one process on each interface simultaneously.

Is it possible? I'm using Ubuntu 12.10.

Comment: What are you trying to do? (ie, why use 2 interfaces?)

Answer (score 0):

When you create a socket, you can `bind()` it to a specific IP address.  Whichever interface is associated with that address will be used.